# (403) Forbidden Error on Put but succeeds on retry

Tags: google-drive-api

In the middle of a program with many Puts like this:

> 2020-07-20 21:48:20 -04 -: Put - Started: b4bc325b682cf4f3199737dbc95d54d8c.dblock.zip.aes (49.92 MB)

> 2020-07-20 22:00:48 -04 - [Retry-RetryPut]: Operation Put with file b4bc325b682cf4f3199737dbc95d54d8c.dblock.zip.aes attempt 1 of 5 failed with message: The remote server returned an error: (403) Forbidden.

I get the Forbidden message. They are all going to the same folder but some like this fail and then succeed on retries.

When I look at the documented 403 errors and what messages go with them in the following URL, Forbidden is not one of them

https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/handle-errors

Does anyone have more clarity on 403 Forbidden

Comment: Actually 403 is documented at the link you gave, add says: "An error 403 occurs when a usage limit has been exceeded or the user doesn't have the correct privileges." If a retry succeeds, I expect it's a usage limit you're hitting.

Comment: Sellotape: If you look a little further it actually has a message for each condition, but "Forbiden" is not one of them. Also this account has no space limit, and as for privilege it succeeds on a retry seconds later., There are 100s of similar puts writing files to the same folder, and this one is no different than most that succeed the first time. I'm trying to figure out the precise reason for the retries.

Comment: 403 and "forbidden" are [synonymous](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-6.5.3) in HTTP, so 403 always means (some variant of) forbidden. Google is using the same code to cover a range of different reasons why they are forbidding your request. They do say that the response also contains a "JSON object in the response body with additional details"; if you're able to see that, things might become clearer.

Comment: What is the exact request you are performing for all thoses files? Can you provide a code snippet? Can you make out a difference between working and not working requests (files on a shared drive? files to which you have readonly access?). How many request per minute / per day do you perform?

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that Google doesn't like you sending too many PUTs too quickly. You need to throttle them at the client. You can get away with 20 or so in rapid succession before you start to see this error. Once you get it, slow your submission rate down to approx 1 every 1.5 seconds. You can try speeding up until the error comes back, then slow down again.

Ignore anybody who advises you to implement exponential backoff - they're lying.

See also https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/36758996 which is a bug you'll trip over if you don't throttle (although PUT is normally idempotent so will affect you less than if you were POSTing new files).

Comment: If its the rate of puts shouldn't I get   "code": 403,
  "message": "User Rate Limit Exceeded" instead of Forbidden as in the API doc I posted above?

Comment: I suspect you are at the http level but whatever code is generating the error message has disguised it. There are various ways to confirm my suspicion.  1/ look at the raw http , 2/ does the error start after the first 20-30 PUTs, 3/ does the error go away if you slow down your PUTs to approx one very 2 seconds.